# Who broke chat?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Did someone unplug the chat server to plug the vacuum cleaner in to get the ants out of the keyboard?

Comment: works for me...

Comment: @studiohack: Perhaps works for people that are already there, but it is down.

Comment: @studiohack: Dincha think it was getting kinda lonely though!?

Comment: [status-not-our-fault] (:

Comment: @Linker3000: that was precisely my thought at one point lol

Comment: Well - this seems as good a place as any to chat...? So much for redundancy and fault tolerance eh!?

Comment: @Linker3000: I can't see who is online... :(

Answer (score 2):

### Edit: We've got news!

> Our data center in Oregon (which hosts chat, but not SO), is currently down.
> The guys there are working on it.

— [Message from @balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83181/chat-and-blog-and-sede-servers-down/83183#83183)

---

### Confirmed...

*Doesn't work here either, from Telenet, Belgium*.

`nslookup chat.stackexchange.com 8.8.4.4` **reveals that DNS is OK**:

```
Server:  google-public-dns-b.google.com
Address:  8.8.4.4

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    chat.stackexchange.com
Address:  69.59.196.211
```

`ipconfig /flushdns && pathping chat.stackexchange.com` **doesn't reach the goal**:

```
Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.

Tracing route to chat.stackexchange.com [69.59.196.211]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  TOMWIJ-WIN7 [192.168.1.100]
  1  192.168.1.1
  2  d51528001.access.telenet.be [81.82.128.1]
  3  dD5E0C4C1.access.telenet.be [213.224.196.193]
  4  dD5E0FD59.access.telenet.be [213.224.253.89]
  5  dD5E0FDB9.access.telenet.be [213.224.253.185]
  6  ae0-0-xcr1.bru.cw.net [62.208.33.65]
  7  xe-10-0-0-xcr1.amd.cw.net [195.2.25.85]
  8  20gigabitethernet1-3.core1.ams1.he.net [195.69.145.150]
  9  10gigabitethernet1-4.core1.lon1.he.net [72.52.92.81]
 10  10gigabitethernet4-4.core1.nyc4.he.net [72.52.92.241]
 11  10gigabitethernet8-3.core1.chi1.he.net [72.52.92.178]
 12  10gigabitethernet3-2.core1.den1.he.net [184.105.213.86]
 13  10gigabitethernet3-4.core1.sea1.he.net [184.105.213.41]
 14  10gigabitethernet1-2.core1.pdx1.he.net [72.52.92.10]
 15     *        *        *

 Computing statistics for 350 seconds...

                 Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0                                           TOMWIJ-WIN7 [192.168.1.100]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  1    1ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.1.1
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  2    9ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  d51528001.access.telenet.be [81.82.128.1]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  3  ---     100/ 100 =100%   100/ 100 =100%  dD5E0C4C1.access.telenet.be [213.224.196.193]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  4  ---     100/ 100 =100%   100/ 100 =100%  dD5E0FD59.access.telenet.be [213.224.253.89]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  5  ---     100/ 100 =100%   100/ 100 =100%  dD5E0FDB9.access.telenet.be [213.224.253.185]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  6   12ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  ae0-0-xcr1.bru.cw.net [62.208.33.65]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  7   15ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  xe-10-0-0-xcr1.amd.cw.net [195.2.25.85]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  8  ---     100/ 100 =100%   100/ 100 =100%  20gigabitethernet1-3.core1.ams1.he.net [195.69.145.150]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  9   32ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  10gigabitethernet1-4.core1.lon1.he.net [72.52.92.81]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 10   95ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  10gigabitethernet4-4.core1.nyc4.he.net [72.52.92.241]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 11  127ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  10gigabitethernet8-3.core1.chi1.he.net [72.52.92.178]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 12  159ms     1/ 100 =  1%     1/ 100 =  1%  10gigabitethernet3-2.core1.den1.he.net [184.105.213.86]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 13  182ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  10gigabitethernet3-4.core1.sea1.he.net [184.105.213.41]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 14  179ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  10gigabitethernet1-2.core1.pdx1.he.net [72.52.92.10]

Trace complete.
```

[Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) **confirms that the goal is unreachable over HTTP**:

> HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
> Content-Type: text/html
> Connection: close
> Timestamp: 21:53:57.131
>
> **[Fiddler]** Connection to chat.stackexchange.com failed.
>
> **Exception Text:**
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 69.59.196.211:80

Comment: good work @TomWiji! +1

Comment: @Rebecca: Thank you, as I spent a bit more time on the post than expected I was in a hurry at the end to go back and continue on my homework project to match a deadline. :)

Comment: Wow you guys get bored when you're not chatting.