# Add 'Fault' to the Meta required tag list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta-tags

Is it possible to add something like 'Fault' or 'Failure' or 'Crash' to the list of tags that you have to pick one of in order to post to Meta?  For example, with yesterday's data centre down-ness ("[Who broke chat?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2193/who-broke-chat)") I didn't really want to post to the main SU page, but it didn't really come under "Bug" or "Feature Request" - it would have been happier under a tag of "Fault" or something similar.  And it wasn't really a "support" request.  I guess it could have gone under "discussion", but that didn't really sit right with me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the required tag you are looking for already exists and is

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Comment: It wasn't really a support request.  It was more reporting a fault.  To my mind a support request would be if I wanted help with something.  A network failure (or something like that) isn't really a support request.

Comment: @matt yes it is, it's a support request to *diagnose and fix the network failure*

Comment: I guess if you word it like that it could just about go in support.  Fair enough, you win ;)

Comment: @matt we both win! win-win-win!

Comment: @Jeff Can I win too?

Comment: @blood here's some win for you too http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJbAT1wzS8U

Comment: @Jeff ok, that's a win for sure...